# Solr : range queries on multiValued fields in sub-entities?

Tags: solr, range

I'm using Solr to index some stuff.

I got a **dataconfig.xml** with a root entity and a sub entity, like this one :

```
<entity name="item" query="select id, qty from item">
    <field column="id" name="id" />
    <field column="qty" name="qty" />

    <entity name="prices" query="select price from prices where item_id='${item.id}'">
        <field column="price" name="price" />
    </entity>

</entity>
```

And the corresponding **schema.xml** :

```
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="qty" type="sint" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="price" type="sint" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
</fields>
```

Fields **qty** (from the root entity) and **price** (from the sub-entity) are both of type *sint* (to allow range queries), and **price** is *multiValued* since there can be multiple prices values for one item.

When I do a range query on qty, it works as expected. For example, `qty:[* TO 10]` returns elements with qty up to 10.

But when I do a range query on price, it doesn't work at all : `price:[* TO 100]` returns elements with prices even over 100 !

Hence my question: *are range queries supposed to work on multiValued fields from "sub-entities" ?*

Comment: I'm not that much into solr/lucene, but what you're describing makes sense to me, what you expect doesn't. Suppose you have a entity with two prices - 50 and 200. price:[* TO 100] will obviously find it. The found entity will also have a price that's > 100.

You could add multiple documents to the solr index, one for each price, and have the price field single valued. You'd still be able to retrieve all prices, by searching by id after a search by price.